# Column dictionary values into separate Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe which has a column that contains a list of dictionaries. This is what an example column value it looks like:

```
[{'score': 0.09248554706573486, 'category': 'soccer', 'threshold': 0.13000713288784027}, {'score': 0.09267200529575348, 'category': 'soccer', 'threshold': 0.11795613169670105}, {'score': 0.1703065186738968, 'category': 'soccer', 'threshold': 0.2004493921995163}, {'score': 0.08060390502214432, 'category': 'basketball', 'threshold': 0.09613725543022156}, {'score': 0.16494056582450867, 'category': 'basketball', 'threshold': 0.2284235805273056}, {'score': 0.008428425528109074, 'category': 'basketball', 'threshold': 0.018201233819127083}, {'score': 0.0761604905128479, 'category': 'hockey', 'threshold': 0.0924532413482666}, {'score': 0.10853488743305206, 'category': 'basketball', 'threshold': 0.1252049058675766}, {'score': 0.0012563085183501244, 'category': 'soccer', 'threshold': 0.008611497469246387}, {'score': 0.058744996786117554, 'category': 'soccer', 'threshold': 0.08366610109806061}, {'score': 0.20794744789600372, 'category': 'rugby', 'threshold': 0.26308900117874146}, {'score': 0.1463163197040558, 'category': 'hockey', 'threshold': 0.18053030967712402}, {'score': 0.12938784062862396, 'category': 'hockey', 'threshold': 0.13267497718334198}, {'score': 0.09140244871377945, 'category': 'basketball', 'threshold': 0.13820350170135498}, {'score': 0.06976936012506485, 'category': 'hockey', 'threshold': 0.0989123210310936}, {'score': 0.05813559517264366, 'category': 'basketball', 'threshold': 0.06885409355163574}, {'score': 0.09365707635879517, 'category': 'hockey', 'threshold': 0.12393374741077423},]
```

I want to create a separate dataframe that takes the above column values for each row, and produces a dataframe where 'category' is a column, and the values for that columns are score and threshold.

For example:

```
category | score                  | threshold
soccer   | 0.09248554706573486    | 0.13000713288784027
soccer   | 0.09267200529575348    | 0.13000713288784027
soccer   | 0.1703065186738968     | 0.13000713288784027
basketball  | 0.16494056582450867   | 0.018201233819127083
basketball  | 0.08060390502214432   | 0.018201233819127083
basketball  | 0.10853488743305206   | 0.018201233819127083
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `lst` the input list, simply use the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

output:

```
       score    category  threshold
0   0.092486      soccer   0.130007
1   0.092672      soccer   0.117956
2   0.170307      soccer   0.200449
3   0.080604  basketball   0.096137
4   0.164941  basketball   0.228424
5   0.008428  basketball   0.018201
6   0.076160      hockey   0.092453
7   0.108535  basketball   0.125205
8   0.001256      soccer   0.008611
9   0.058745      soccer   0.083666
10  0.207947       rugby   0.263089
11  0.146316      hockey   0.180530
12  0.129388      hockey   0.132675
13  0.091402  basketball   0.138204
14  0.069769      hockey   0.098912
15  0.058136  basketball   0.068854
16  0.093657      hockey   0.123934
```

If you have such list for each item in the series, use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
df2 = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df['col']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your answer works if I only apply it to the first row. Each row has a list of dictionaries, and I want to get dataframe like that for all the rows.

Comment: You want one DataFrame that combines all the rows or one DataFrame per row?

Comment: One dataframe that combines all the rows

Comment: Ok, then `from itertools import chain ; df2 = pd.DataFrame(chain(df['col']))`

Comment: @Nick hadn't seen it (on phone), upvoted. That said `chain` is likely more efficient than repeated instanciation of the DataFrame constructor. ;)

Comment: @user872009 it should be `chain.from_iterable`: `from itertools import chain ; df2 = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df['col']))`, let me add this cleanly to the answer

Comment: @Nick I guess the voters interpreted the question as I initially did, that the input was the full Series. But I agree that sometimes votes are not always reflecting a careful review of an answer, I've seen so many times multi-upvoted answers that were simply incorrect would anyone have just tried to run them ;)

Comment: You could also `chain(*df['col'])`

Comment: Yes I used to do that, but I seem to recall this is less efficient than `from_iterable` due to unpacking [reference needed]

Comment: mmmm... but I suspect given you have to unroll all the data anyway there wouldn't be much in it...

Comment: @Nick quick test on a list of 1M items and `from_iterable` is ~30% faster

Comment: There you go. Thanks for that, I'll make sure to use `from_iterable` in the future.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you need to iterate the values in the column, converting them to dataframes and appending them to a new dataframe. For example:

```py
dout = pd.DataFrame()
for dd in df['col']:
    dout = pd.concat([dout, pd.DataFrame(dd)])
dout = dout.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or as a comprehension:

```py
dout = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(v) for v in df['col']).reset_index(drop=True)
```